# Javascript continues slider

Tags: javascript, html

I'm writing a simple image slider and my problem is when it reaches the end of the slider it stops.
What I need is to continue at the end of the slider that it will display the first image in the slider
and continue to slide until the onKeyup event fires...

any help is appreciated :)

here is my code:

```
    var second_array = new Array();
function LoadImageList() {
    var s = "";
    var ia = 0;
    var std = "";
    var etd = "";
    var paths = FSO.OpenTextFile("bin\\Tlist.txt")

    while (!paths.AtEndOfStream) {
    var tot = ia++;
    content = paths.ReadLine();
    var newNameN = content.split(";");
    var curID = "t"+tot
    var forID = "t"+parseFloat(tot+1)
    var bacID = "t"+parseFloat(tot-1)

        second_array[tot] = "<td nowrap style=\"padding:10px;\"><font style=\"display:none;\">"+newNameN[0]+"</font><img src=\""+newNameN[2]+"\\folderS.jpg\" id=\""+curID+"\" tabindex=\""+tot+"\" style=\"width:217px; height:322px; border:solid 5px silver; border-radius:10px; box-shadow: 0 0 15px #fff; cursor: pointer;\" onMouseOver=\"this.style.border='solid 5px red';\" onMouseOut=\"this.style.border='solid 5px silver';\"></td>";

    }
    second_array.sort();
        var tempList = second_array.join("");
            thumb.innerHTML = "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 border=0><tr>"+tempList+"</tr></table>";
}

var defaultStep=1;
var step=defaultStep;
var timerLeft;
var timerRight;

function scrollDivLeft(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).scrollLeft+=Math.round(step*100);
    timerLeft=setTimeout("scrollDivLeft('"+id+"')",1);
} 

function scrollDivRight(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).scrollLeft-=Math.round(step*100);
    timerRight=setTimeout("scrollDivRight('"+id+"')",1);
} 

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
if (e.keyCode=='37') {
    clearTimeout(timerRight);
    scrollDivRight("thumb");
    }
    else if (e.keyCode=='39') {
    clearTimeout(timerLeft);
    scrollDivLeft("thumb");
    }
})

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode=='37') {
    clearTimeout(timerRight);
    }
    else if (e.keyCode=='39') {
    clearTimeout(timerLeft);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Imagine your list of scrollable images is set up like this, and the user is viewing the last  item:

```
<li>Img 1</li> (out of view)
<li>Img 2</li> (out of view)
<li>Img 3</li> (out of view)
<li>Img 4</li> (Visible item)
```

At this point you have a few options, depending on how you want the slider to function.  The simplest way would be to scroll back to the first image when the user clicks next.  That would give you a sort of "continuous scroll" but it would be very clear which item is first and which is last.

Another option is to append the first image to the end of the list.  In that case, the list would actually look like this when the user is viewing the last image:

```
<li>Img 2</li> (out of view)
<li>Img 3</li> (out of view)
<li>Img 4</li> (Visible item)
<li>Img 1</li> (Clone of first item appended to end of list, out of view)
```

You can handle the logic to clone the list item separately from the scroll logic.  This is roughly how the commonly used jQuery slider plugins handle it.

In pseudocode you might have something like this:

```
    function scrollDivRight(id) {
        if ( current item position is 2nd to last ) {
            Clone & remove item1
            Append item1 to end
        }        
        scrolling logic
    }
```

For more details I suggest looking at the [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) source code.

If you include a sample Tlist.txt file it would be easier to test the code and provide a more specific answer.

Comment: The Tlist.txt is list of paths to the thumbImage nothing special there... I'll be glad to stick to simple code not involving with jQuery and such... all the thumb images in the list are visible to the user nothing is out of view... I'm stuck :(

Comment: Sorry, I think I misread some of your code the first time around.  I will take another shot an answer later on today of no one gets to it.  Putting something up in jsfiddle.net would probably help your get some more responses.

Comment: well I guess I stack with this one forever... bumer :(